# Order of response in Google Adwords API

Tags: python, google-ads-api

Are there any guarantees the Google Adwords API can make about the order of the entries in the response when creating objects calling `mutate()`?

For example if the request was sent something like:

```
operations = [add_adgroup_1, add_adgroup_2, add_adgroup_3]
response = client.mutate(operations)

print response['entries'] 
# >> [adgroup_1, adgroup_2, adgroup_3]
```

is the order `[adgroup_1, adgroup_2, adgroup_3]` in the `response['entries']` guaranteed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are according to the AdWords API Team: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/6Jpcc6dnr-M